# Unable to update the HTML 5 data attribute array

Tags: jquery

When i click on the Addons Button and check / uncheck   the items (Checkboxes ) , i am updating the data array

But even after setting the data ,when i inspect the element  i see the data -stuff array is still empty

```
<div class="lastItm_Wrap" data-stuff="[]">

</div>
```

could you please let me know how to set data /  update data stuff array

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/102/

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667732/data-attribute-value-updated-by-jquery-is-not-visible-in-dom) answers your question.

Comment: @Yangu ..., consetetur sadipscing elitr?

Comment: @Martin, ipsam voluptatem.

Comment: I think this comments do nothing to solve the problem. I am sure we could write the whole "lorem ipsum"-paragraph here until we were flagged :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the attribute value instead of setting its data property.

change

```
 $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff', vendoritemsdata);
```

to

```
 $('.lastItm_Wrap').attr('data-stuff', vendoritemsdata);
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

You are using the jQuery data-api, which has an internal storage to store the data values that is why the attribute value is not updated.

Your values are set properly in the internal storage so it should be fine.

```
// checkbox checked
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event) {
    var vendoritemsdata = $(".lastItm_Wrap").data('stuff');
    var checkboxid = $(this).next().attr("id");
    vendoritemsdata.push(checkboxid);
    $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff', vendoritemsdata);
    console.log('off',vendoritemsdata)
});

// checkbox Unchecked
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event) {
    var vendoritemsdata = $(".lastItm_Wrap").data('stuff');
    var itemtoRemove = $(this).next().attr("id");

    vendoritemsdata.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, vendoritemsdata), 1);
    console.log('on',vendoritemsdata)

    $('.lastItm_Wrap').data('stuff', vendoritemsdata);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/abs4vs5o/1/)

Look at the logged values in the console and you could see that it is working fine